# Request cluster id from cluster name

Tags: orientdb, orientdb-2.1

Is there a way to request the cluster id from a cluster name?

Context:
In our context the default cluster allow child cluster to see, but not update, the data. I would like to notify the user that it is looking at data provided from a different cluster than its own.

Example

```
Cluster Product
#15:0 // cluster name : product. Product provided from head office
#115:0 //cluster name : productmybranch. Product provided from the branch
```

The branch sees the product from the head office, but should not update it. The `oRoles` fixes that.

How can I know that a branch user is currently looking at a product from the head office?

I was looking for a request like (That query does not work)

```
select metatdata:cluster from cluster:productmybranch
```

Or any way via the JAVA API

(running on orientdb 2.1.0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done it through the Java API. The call to getClusterIdByName just looks up the class/table name in a ConcurrentHashMap that the OrientDB Java API uses.

```
OObjectDatabaseTx objectDB = OObjectDatabasePool.global().setup(1, 4).acquire(dbName, dbUser, dbPassword);
int clusterId = objectDB.getClusterIdByName("ClassName");
objectDB.close();
```

Answer (score 2):

this might help you at least with knowing, it isn't directly possible.

[Can I access Cluster/s name for objects during a query on OrientDB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32658980/can-i-access-cluster-s-name-for-objects-during-a-query-on-orientdb)

Scott